# Linux PCI register read too slow

Tags: c, linux

Now I have to write one PCI device driver. I use memory map method to access the PCI-card address space.

But now, when I use `readl` macro to read one register on the PCI-card, it costs 1 µs time — is this normal?

code:(COMEDI project source code)

```
addr = pci_resource_start(pcidev, 0);//BAR0 address
mite->mite_phys_addr = addr;
mite->mite_io_addr = ioremap(addr, PCI_MITE_SIZE);//memory map 
if (!mite->mite_io_addr) 
{
    printk("failed to remap mite io memory address\n");
    return -ENOMEM;
}
```

Then can use the mite->mite_io_addr access PCI-card device address space

Comment: Add the code that you use to memory map.

Comment: The total time to read through a PCI register can be quite long. I'm not sure what the "normal" time is, but 1 us doesn't seem entirely crazy for a random read.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have add the code.But my application is hard real-time,so "1us" is too long...